# Deploying a .net Web Package in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, visual-studio-2012

So I have a Windows server with this mysterious thing called IIS. I have made a .net website within Visual Studio 2012. I published my website BUILD > Publish Web Site > Profile > Connection "Web Deploy Package" > Etc. So this process has created a web package which I believe I can deploy into IIS.

From IIS I Deploy > Import Application > Select my Web package and it sets it all up. Everything looks good in IIS except one major issue the website does now work at all when going to the correct path.

Did I understand this all wrong? Am I doing something incorrectly within the process? Or did I just forget I'm using windows and have to go through the hole deploy crap from visual studio and connect to my server etc?

I was hoping these website packages would be easy to deploy would save a lot of time and make simple changes easy but I'm totally lost as to why its not working?

Error when going to website path:

Server Error

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name         changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: What error(s) do you get when you try to browse to your application after deploying it?

Comment: Ahh good question sorry I did not post this before I should have.Server Error

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Do you see your app in IIS Manager after you import the package?

Comment: I do see the site under my Default Web Site with all correct files etc. However I don't actually see the application running in the app pool but I also have 2 more sites under the Default Web Site that are working correctly but do not show as an application in the app pool. Hope this makes sense sorry!

Comment: My only guess at this point is if you can make web deploy packages and deploy them on your IIS and they aren't used for something else it has to be permissions or an issue with directory access because I did notice when deploying from visual studio itself it sets up permissions etc which takes a min, with the deploy package I never see this process.

Comment: Ok.  There are a ton of things that could be going wrong, but not enough info to pinpoint.  It's not permissions, that would yield a 403.  IIS is not able to map your incoming request to your application for some reason - typo from the browser, bad host bindings, bad URL routing (depends on what kind of asp.net app it is)...  Is this an MVC app?  What do the bindings look like on the virtual directory that was created in IIS?  (Double check the URL you used in the browser to rule out the painfully obvious)

Comment: Its an MVC App. I double checked the browser url, and also tested right clicking and browsing the application from IIS still same error. Physical Path is good, Virtual path is just /InstSets but matches the same schema as the other sites. https protocol is enabled I tried reaching the site with and without https. I'm going to check routing now. Thanks for all your help btw.